# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined MERN stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I am building an admin login page using MERN Stack. The data is on my MongoDB cluster on Atlas. I am getting error:

```
(node:11648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
   at /home/dell/Desktop/Coding/photography/backend/index.js:24:24
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/dell/Desktop/Coding/photography/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at invokeCallback (/home/dell/Desktop/Coding/photography/backend/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11648) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11648) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am have Admin component in React:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AdminLogin = () => {

  const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const checkAdmin = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1377/admin/login", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
       username,
       password,
     }),
   });

  const data = await response.json();

  console.log(data);
};

return (
  <>
    <div className="admin-form">
      <div className="admin">
        <div className="admin-username admin-input">
          <label htmlFor="username" className="label">
            Username:
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter admin username"
            className="input"
            id="username"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="admin-password admin-input">
          <label htmlFor="password" className="label">
            Password:
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            className="input"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button className="submit" onClick={checkAdmin}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
);
};
export default AdminLogin;
```

This is my index.js in backend folder:

```
// Importing modules and packages

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./models/user.model");

// Connecting to MongoDB
// Ignore <username> and <password> in MongoDB URL

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@photography.4ssji.mongodb.net/<project>? 
   retryWrites=true&w=majority"
);

// Setting up middleware

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Creating express server

app.post("/admin/login", async (res, req) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
  username: req.body.username,
 });

 if (user) {
   return res.json({ status: "ok", admin: true });
 } else {
   return res.json({ status: "error", admin: false });
 }
});

app.get((req, res, next) => {
  res.send("404 not found");
});

app.listen(1377, () => {
 console.log("Server started successfully on PORT: 1377");
});
```

This is my user model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const User = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { collection: "user-data" }
);

const model = mongoose.model("UserData", User);

module.exports = model;
```

The error says that the username has the property of undefined but I can't find any username which has property undefined. The admin page is for a photographer's website to showcase his photography and using the admin page he can add or delete the content from the website. I am following a tutorial to make this admin page which is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ejg7es3ba2k

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post("/admin/login", async (req, res) => {
```

Your code is fine, you just have a typo here in this line of code in the server file.

**req is 1st arg and res is the 2nd arg.**

Comment: Thank you, I never knew this can be a problem.